# rand() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given

Tags: php

I get the error:

> rand() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given

PHP code:

```
 // Set global last updated time
 $ab_options['lastupdate'] = time();
 ab_saveOptions();

 $this->ab_logMsg('Setting last update time to '.date("g:i a", $ab_options['lastupdate']), AB_LOG_INFO + AB_LOG_ONLY, 'debug');
 set_transient('Auto_LastRun', time(), 3600);
 set_transient('Auto_Interval', rand($ab_options['mintime'], $ab_options['maxtime']), 86400);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ab_options['mintime']` must be an integer or a numeric string. Try running `var_dump($ab_options['mintime']);` to see the value. The same applies to the second argument.